# Using Google Map Directions API with alamofire 4.0 and iOS 10 Swift

Tags: swift, alamofire, ios10

My project is currently built in xcode 8/swift 3 with alamofire 4.0 .

My podfile is as follows:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'CustomerApp' do

# Pods for CustomerApp
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
pod 'GoogleMapsDirections', '~>1.0.4'
pod 'Alamofire', '~>4.0'

end
```

I get the following error in the terminal when trying to install the googleMapDirection pod:

] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Alamofire (~> 4.0)` required by `Podfile`
- `Alamofire (= 4.2.0)` required by `Podfile.lock`
- `Alamofire (~> 3.0)` required by `GoogleMapsDirections (1.0.4)`

Specs satisfying the `Alamofire (~> 4.0), Alamofire (= 4.2.0), Alamofire (~> 3.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Google Map Directions works with previous versions of Alamofire (3.5) but i cant get it working with 4.0. Am i doing something wrong here? is anyone else having the same problem/ found a fix?

Answer (score 1):

**Solved:**

I have change the version of `GoogleMapDirections to 1.1` in my pod file which requires the latest `Alamofire v4.0` dependency.

[image]